# psql table subselection based on count

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table for which I count the number of rows for each distinct id. 
If the number of rows is >= 6, then I would like to select from the original table only the rows with the id's that returned from the query.

I managed to write the first part of the code as seen below.

```
select * from (select id, count(*) from flights group by id) as fcount where count >= 6
```

Now, how do i select from table flights all the rows matching the id's giving by the first selection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a subquery to do your first part: `SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM flights GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 6`. You don't even need to select COUNT(*) since you don't care about the actual number. From this, it should be obvious how to use the resulting list of ids to get the data you want.

Comment: Do you happen to know in advance if the number of flights with a count of >= 6 are either a significant minority or significant majority? If so there may be a more efficient way to write the query than what's been given so far.

Comment: I plotted distribution of the number of counts  and flights with >= 6 counts are significant majority in the dataset.

Comment: Check the query plan or efficiency of this, see if it's any good: `SELECT *
    FROM flights
    WHERE NOT id = ANY(ARRAY((SELECT id FROM flights f GROUP BY f.id HAVING COUNT(*) < 6)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT f.*
            ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS fcount
        FROM flights f
        ) s
    WHERE fcount >= 6
```

Or this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Flights fo
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM flights fi
        WHERE fi.id = fo.id
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 6
        )
```